# NodeJS Crypto module using SEED cipher algorithm

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, cryptography, cryptojs

I need to use the "SEED" cipher algorithm, which seems that it was supported by Crypto module in the past. When I try to get which ciphers are currently supported using `crypto.getCiphers()` I got this result :

```
  'aes-128-cbc',
  'aes-128-cfb',
  'aes-128-ctr',
  'aes-128-ecb',
  'aes-128-gcm',
  'aes-128-ofb',
  'aes-192-cbc',
  'aes-192-ctr',
  'aes-192-ecb',
  'aes-192-gcm',
  'aes-192-ofb',
  'aes-256-cbc',
  'aes-256-cfb',
  'aes-256-ctr',
  'aes-256-ecb',
  'aes-256-gcm',
  'aes-256-ofb',
  'des-cbc',
  'des-ecb',
  'des-ede',
  'des-ede-cbc',
  'des-ede3-cbc',
  'rc2-cbc',
  'rc4'
```

I've tried using many Node versions and the results are always the same. Also, I've tried to use openssl from my application but SEED cipher are not available anymore. 
How can I add support for this cipher algorithm in my application ? 
Tested with Node 12, 11, 10, 9, 8. OpenSSL version : LibreSSL 2.6.5

TIA !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the version of NodeJS, it's a problem with the LibreSSL library, which maybe didn't include it because it is a country specific cipher.

It's documentation reads:

> Symmetric ciphers including AES, Blowfish, CAST, Chacha20, IDEA, DES, RC2, and RC4

and SEED is not there in the [`EVP_EncryptInit` documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/EVP_EncryptInit.3) either.

If I however look at OpenSSL v1.1.1c as present on my system, the SEED cipher is still listed in the `openssl help` page. So you need to use a different cryptographic library as backend.

---

Note that the LibreSSL goals page contains:

> Remove obsolete or broken features and operating system support

LibreSSL tries to remove features that may not be needed anymore, and SEED is very likely one of the many ciphers that can be missed.

Answer (score 1):

SEED is just a 16-round Feistel network with 128-bit blocks and a 128-bit key, it's definitely not something I would use in production.

For what it's worth SEED is still present in **node 13**.

on `macOS 10.15.3` running `node.js v13.7.0`, I executed this code:

```
  1 var crypto = require('crypto')
  2 const util = require('util');
  3 util.inspect.defaultOptions.maxArrayLength = null;
  4 
  5
  6 console.log(crypto.getCiphers())
```

Which indeed lists SEED as a supported cipher:

```
[
  'aes-128-cbc',
  'aes-128-ccm',
  'aes-128-cfb',
  'aes-128-cfb1',
  'aes-128-cfb8',
  'aes-128-ctr',
  'aes-128-ecb',
  'aes-128-gcm',
  'aes-128-ocb',
  'aes-128-ofb',
  'aes-128-xts',
  'aes-192-cbc',
  'aes-192-ccm',
  'aes-192-cfb',
  'aes-192-cfb1',
  'aes-192-cfb8',
  'aes-192-ctr',
  'aes-192-ecb',
  'aes-192-gcm',
  'aes-192-ocb',
  'aes-192-ofb',
  'aes-256-cbc',
  'aes-256-ccm',
  'aes-256-cfb',
  'aes-256-cfb1',
  'aes-256-cfb8',
  'aes-256-ctr',
  'aes-256-ecb',
  'aes-256-gcm',
  'aes-256-ocb',
  'aes-256-ofb',
  'aes-256-xts',
  'aes128',
  'aes128-wrap',
  'aes192',
  'aes192-wrap',
  'aes256',
  'aes256-wrap',
  'aria-128-cbc',
  'aria-128-ccm',
  'aria-128-cfb',
  'aria-128-cfb1',
  'aria-128-cfb8',
  'aria-128-ctr',
  'aria-128-ecb',
  'aria-128-gcm',
  'aria-128-ofb',
  'aria-192-cbc',
  'aria-192-ccm',
  'aria-192-cfb',
  'aria-192-cfb1',
  'aria-192-cfb8',
  'aria-192-ctr',
  'aria-192-ecb',
  'aria-192-gcm',
  'aria-192-ofb',
  'aria-256-cbc',
  'aria-256-ccm',
  'aria-256-cfb',
  'aria-256-cfb1',
  'aria-256-cfb8',
  'aria-256-ctr',
  'aria-256-ecb',
  'aria-256-gcm',
  'aria-256-ofb',
  'aria128',
  'aria192',
  'aria256',
  'bf',
  'bf-cbc',
  'bf-cfb',
  'bf-ecb',
  'bf-ofb',
  'blowfish',
  'camellia-128-cbc',
  'camellia-128-cfb',
  'camellia-128-cfb1',
  'camellia-128-cfb8',
  'camellia-128-ctr',
  'camellia-128-ecb',
  'camellia-128-ofb',
  'camellia-192-cbc',
  'camellia-192-cfb',
  'camellia-192-cfb1',
  'camellia-192-cfb8',
  'camellia-192-ctr',
  'camellia-192-ecb',
  'camellia-192-ofb',
  'camellia-256-cbc',
  'camellia-256-cfb',
  'camellia-256-cfb1',
  'camellia-256-cfb8',
  'camellia-256-ctr',
  'camellia-256-ecb',
  'camellia-256-ofb',
  'camellia128',
  'camellia192',
  'camellia256',
  'cast',
  'cast-cbc',
  'cast5-cbc',
  'cast5-cfb',
  'cast5-ecb',
  'cast5-ofb',
  'chacha20',
  'chacha20-poly1305',
  'des',
  'des-cbc',
  'des-cfb',
  'des-cfb1',
  'des-cfb8',
  'des-ecb',
  'des-ede',
  'des-ede-cbc',
  'des-ede-cfb',
  'des-ede-ecb',
  'des-ede-ofb',
  'des-ede3',
  'des-ede3-cbc',
  'des-ede3-cfb',
  'des-ede3-cfb1',
  'des-ede3-cfb8',
  'des-ede3-ecb',
  'des-ede3-ofb',
  'des-ofb',
  'des3',
  'des3-wrap',
  'desx',
  'desx-cbc',
  'id-aes128-CCM',
  'id-aes128-GCM',
  'id-aes128-wrap',
  'id-aes128-wrap-pad',
  'id-aes192-CCM',
  'id-aes192-GCM',
  'id-aes192-wrap',
  'id-aes192-wrap-pad',
  'id-aes256-CCM',
  'id-aes256-GCM',
  'id-aes256-wrap',
  'id-aes256-wrap-pad',
  'id-smime-alg-CMS3DESwrap',
  'idea',
  'idea-cbc',
  'idea-cfb',
  'idea-ecb',
  'idea-ofb',
  'rc2',
  'rc2-128',
  'rc2-40',
  'rc2-40-cbc',
  'rc2-64',
  'rc2-64-cbc',
  'rc2-cbc',
  'rc2-cfb',
  'rc2-ecb',
  'rc2-ofb',
  'rc4',
  'rc4-40',
  'rc4-hmac-md5',
  'seed',
  'seed-cbc',
  'seed-cfb',
  'seed-ecb',
  'seed-ofb',
  'sm4',
  'sm4-cbc',
  'sm4-cfb',
  'sm4-ctr',
  'sm4-ecb',
  'sm4-ofb'
]
```

Comment: Of course it isn't "supported"; the implementation of NodeJS just uses whatever is present in the underlying library. If it were supported I would expect it to have an alternative, possibly non-native implementation.